# How to continue poll an API and cancel the polling if a condition is not met

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-services

Here, if pending service is > 0, i want to call a service(http api) to get the new status. I have written following code for this:

```
counter = 1;
getDetatils(){
  this.myService.getDetails().subscribe(services => {
    this.services = services;
    if(this.services.pending.length > 0 && counter <= 10){
      this.getDetails(); // if list of pending item is > 0, do query again.
      counter ++;
    }
})
```

Above code, keep running the function getDetails unless the list of pending services are 0 (maximum 10 times).

But somehow I am not happy with the code structure above. 1st thing I don't want to keep polling every second. May be poll after 5. Somehow I hate using Timeout.

I have tried to use Observable here, but being new to angular2, not sure of its exact usage.

SO my question is, can I use Observable here, which takes care of interval as well as maximum attempt both together? If yes then How? and How I will cancel this if some condition isn't met.

Comment: please let me know if question is not clear...

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to turn the list of pending requests into an Observable?

```ts
class MyPendingService {
  private pending: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  get pendingRequests(): Observable<any> {
    return this.pending.asObservable();
  }

  queueRequest(x: any) {
    this.pending.next(x);
  }
}

// Somewhere else in your codebase you consume your observable
// ...

pendingService.pendingRequests.subscribe((next) => {
  // Replace this with your logic
  console.log("pending", next);
});

// In another place, you produce pending pending requests
// ...

pendingService.queueRequest("1");
pendingService.queueRequest("2");
```

Check out this plunker for a minimal example implementation: https://embed.plnkr.co/9fLBH3YA7BlQw6ndZCFp/